# DocumentDB Queries help/reference

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

EDIT:
I see downvote for this question, editing my question to add clarity and readability.

I'm from SQL background ramping up on Document DB Query syntax.  I'm looking for document db equivalent syntax for the following T-SQL Queries. Any help appreciated.

1. Select * from c where c.header.TimeStampField >= 'Time Stamp Constant'
2. Select * from c where Upper(c.stringifield) = "lowercase to uppercase"
3. select count(1) from c --Find count of all documents

Is it possible to delete the documents thru a query ? like RDBMS queries (delete from table?)

Comment: This is really a set of questions. I'll try to answer below but you should consider breaking it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries #1 and #2 should work exactly as specified.

Query #3 is not possible. However, the total size of documents is returned in the `documentsCount` property in the `x-ms-resource-usage` response header. That's a new feature that may or may not be supported by the SDK you are using though. So, you can get a count of all documents by going through all of the lines. [Here](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils/blob/master/sprocs/countDocuments.coffee) is a fully worked example of doing it in a stored procedure. Alternatively, you could do `SELECT 1 FROM c` and bring back all of the 1's and count/sum them.

It is not possible to delete documents through a query like in SQL. You can do it in a sproc or use the client side functionality for delete document. In both cases, you'd need to first query the docs and then delete them one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

With DocumentDB's latest aggregate support (Feb 2017), you may now generate counts with something like:

```
SELECT VALUE COUNT(1)
FROM mydocuments d
```

This also works with filters. For instance:

```
SELECT VALUE COUNT(1)
FROM mydocuments d
WHERE d.foo = "bar"
```

There's also support for min/max/average/sum.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your query is good already for DocumentDB.
2. Your query is correct and should work. However an additional optimization would be to store a separate property in the same document that has all upper cases and explicitly search for it. This change would use index instead of doing a scan.
3. Larry's answer for #3 is the right way to go about it.

For digging further on the query language, you could use playground @ https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo